# Transparent QImage on QSGTexture

Tags: qt, qml

I am using Qt5.8 on Windows. I have created a QQucikItem which i am rendering on QML. In **updatePaintNode** function i am creating a QImage(which have some transparent part) as **finalImage**

```
QSGSimpleTextureNode *node = 0;
QSGTexture *texture;        
node = static_cast<QSGSimpleTextureNode *>(oldNode);
if (!node) {
    node = new QSGSimpleTextureNode();
}

texture = window()->createTextureFromImage(finalImage);
node->setTexture(texture);
node->setRect(boundingRect());
node->markDirty(QSGNode::DirtyForceUpdate);
return node;
```

so in qml transparent part is becoming *black* instead of *transparent*

Comment: I found there is a bug in drawing of QImage somehow transparent part of image is converting in black.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was creating QImage using RGB32 instead of ARGB32 format.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what are you doing but black background means that image isn't loaded. Usually it's wrong path or something like that. Or may be the image corrupted. You can only fill background intentionally, by default it's transparent.

For example this code:

**C++:**

```
TestItem::TestItem(QQuickItem *parent)
    :QQuickItem(parent)
{
    setFlag(QQuickItem::ItemHasContents);
}

QSGNode *TestItem::updatePaintNode(QSGNode *oldNode, QQuickItem::UpdatePaintNodeData *updatePaintNodeData)
{
    QSGSimpleTextureNode *node = static_cast<QSGSimpleTextureNode *>(oldNode);
    if (!node) {
        node = new QSGSimpleTextureNode();
        QImage img(":/sunflower.png");
        QSGTexture *texture = window()->createTextureFromImage(img);
        node->setTexture(texture);
    }
    node->setRect(boundingRect());
    return node;
}
```

**QML**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import qml.test 1.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true

    LinearGradient {
        anchors.fill: parent
        start: Qt.point(0, 0)
        end: Qt.point(0, 200)
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "lightblue" }
            GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "white" }
        }
    }

    TestItem {
        width: 200
        height: 200
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

produces this result:

[image]

The image was taken from [here](http://images.clipartpanda.com/sunflower-clip-art-RiG6GeLxT.png), resized to 200x200 with GIMP.
The project structure is like this:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for your answer @folibis, but before answer something please read question carefully. I can load my image but there is only problem with transparent part. But same code is working fine in your case.

Comment: Hmm ... ok, thank you for showing me how to properly answer a question.

Comment: Maybe its good idea to share this code somewhere on github as an example, its simple enough for everyone to understand texture part.